# Vertical slider thumb position

Tags: codenameone

I am implementing a vertical slider in codename one as a scrollbar. I followed the same steps as the information stated here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html

However when I set my slider progress to maximum (the height of the list), the thumb is at the bottom of the slider. However if I set my slider progress to 2 times the maximum (2 times the height of the list) the thumb will appear at the top..I'm confused as to why this is happening since I have set the min progress to 0 and max value to the height of the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By definition you can't set the value beyond the maximum and once you do that the results are undefined (as you see in your case). You should bind your setting code to not exceed the maximum space.

Comment: Hm okay..what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear. If I set the maxValue of the slider to 2x the height of the list, then the thumb appears at the top. Otherwise it will remain at the bottom. However when the thumb is at the bottom, I can slide correctly, theres just no thumb with my finger since it stays at the bottom

Comment: To be a little more clear, I set the color of the SliderFull UIID so I can see where the progress is. As I adjust the progress up and down (this works correctly), the scroll thumb remains at the bottom of the slider.

Comment: You need to set it to the scroll height not to the height as the height only shows the display height not the real underlying height. Use getScrollDimension()